# FullText Index first Match position

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-indexing

I want to do FulltextSearch columns in a table to find CompanyInfo that use keyword "Internet Of things" and at what position in Company Description is this word found.

Company table has ID, CompanyName, briefdescription_company. I have built FullText Index on this column with default stoplist.

I want to do this

```
CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.Company, briefdescription_company,'ISABOUT("Internet Of things" weight(.1))',LANGUAGE N'English',1000000) as fti
```

and find the position of the first match only.

How can i do this?

Thanks
Rashmi